# How to customize ButttonSpinner control inside an IntegerUpDown control in Extended WPF Toolkit?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

Sorry I'm pretty newbie in WPF styling. I have this ButtonSpinner control and I set its width and height using the appropriate properties:

```
    <xctk:ButtonSpinner Width="200" SpinnerWidth="100" SpinnerHeight="100">
    </xctk:ButtonSpinner>
```

[image: ButtonSpinner]

And it works as you see the up spinner and down spinner width and height are increased accordingly.

But why I cannot do the same when applying it to the ButtonSpinner inside IntegerUpDown control? (IntegerUpDown theme: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml) :

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Value="1564" Width="200" Height="100">
        <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:ButtonSpinner}">
                <Setter Property="SpinnerWidth" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="SpinnerHeight" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
        </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
</xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

[image: IntegerUpDown]

It still looks the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Reading the Style of InputBase, they are bound to ButtonSpinnerWidth and ButtonSpinnerHeight of InputBase respectively, thus setting those properties should work.

Comment: @emoacht thanks for pointing it out. Now if I want to change the background for example? I don't see the properties for that. I just curious and didn't understand why the code doesn't work? Why couldn't I change the ButtonSpinner's properties inside the IntegerUpDown control. I think I misunderstand something...

Comment: A local value prevails over another value set in a Style. I forgot the link to the official documentation though.

Comment: @emoacht so if in that case, the only fix is to redefine the ControlTemplate?

Comment: @emoacht https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-7.0

I've found the docs after asking ChatGPT. Thanks again for the explanation. Still interested for your thought on the best way to deal with that tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether an implicit `Style` that you add to the `Resources` property of a control is applied to a child element of that control depends on how the template for control is defined.

If the template explicitly sets the `Style` property of the child control as in the example below, the implicit `Style` in `Resources` won't be applied:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}">
    ...
    <xctk:ButtonSpinner Style="{StaticResource someCustomStyle}" ... />
```

Also, if the template sets the local value of a dependency property of a child control, you cannot set this property using a `Style` as the local value takes [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) over a value specified by a `Setter` of a `Style`.

Comment: Thanks. 

"If the template explicitly sets the Style property of the child control as in the example below, the implicit Style in Resources won't be applied"

So the only workaround for this is to redefine the ControlTemplate?

Comment: In that case, yes. Or change the style programmatically after the control has been loaded.